# Reading a new line from text file using StreamReader

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

What I have stored in my file is values related to an account. (Just testing, not going to be used commercially). What I need is to draw the values for the username and password, by going through each new line, but .peek() doesn't seem to work for me. What am i doing wrong? My block looks as such :

```
        public string CheckAccount(string username, string password)
    {
        StreamReader sr;
        string filename = "H:\\AccountInfo.txt";
        string s;
        string result = "";
        sr = File.OpenText(filename);
        s = sr.ReadLine();
        string usernameFromText;
        string passwordFromText;
        while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
        {
            usernameFromText = (s.Split(','))[0];
            passwordFromText = (s.Split(','))[2];
            if (username == usernameFromText && password == passwordFromText)
            {
                result = "Successfully Logged in!";
            }
            else if (username != usernameFromText || password != passwordFromText)
            {
                result = "Your Username / Password is Invalid!";
            }
        }
        sr.Close();

        return result;
    }
```

My code doesn't read from the 2nd line onwards, it just hangs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear why you're using `sr.Peek` at all... and you're never reading a second line from the file. After the first `ReadLine`, you're never actually moving the file's "cursor" - you're just peeking at the same character repeatedly. If you're using .NET 4, the easiest approach is to use [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx):

```
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(filename))
{
    string usernameFromText = (line.Split(','))[0];
    string passwordFromText = (line.Split(','))[2];
    if (username == usernameFromText && password == passwordFromText)
    {
         return "Successfully Logged in!";
    }
}
return "Your Username / Password is Invalid!";
```

If you're using .NET 3.5 and the file isn't too big, you could read the whole file with [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c4w9x9x.aspx) instead... or there are other alternatives for reading a line at a time.

Note that I've changed the logic to something I suspect is closer to what you really want - namely that the result is success if *any* of the lines matches, and failure otherwise.

Also note that in your original code you wouldn't have closed the reader if an exception were thrown in the loop - you should use a `using` statement to avoid that.

Another option is to use LINQ:

```
var query = from line in File.ReadLines()
            let split = line.Split(',')
            select new { user = split[0], password = split[2] };

return query.Any(x => x.user == username && x.password == password) ?
           "Successfully Logged in!" : "Your Username / Password is Invalid!";
```

Answer (score 6):

In your loop, you keep `Peek`ing instead of calling `ReadLine`.

Answer (score 2):

It's more simpler to use File.ReadLines  and read all lines from file into a string array, something like this:

```
  string[] lines = File.ReadLines("H:\\AccountInfo.txt");
  foreach(string oneLine in lines)
  {
    /// do something with line
  }
```

Comment: It's even better to use File.ReadLines if you're using .NET 4... no need to load the whole file in to start with.

Answer (score 1):

```
        string result;
        StreamReader SR;
        string S;
        SR=File.OpenText("H:\\Account.txt");
        S=SR.ReadToEnd();
        SR.Close();

        string words = S;
        words = words.Replace("\r", string.Empty);
        List<string> splitNewLine = words.Split('\n').ToList();

        for (int i = 0; i <= splitNewLine.Count() - 1; i++)
        {
            string checkUsername = (splitNewLine[i].Split(','))[0];
            string checkPassword = (splitNewLine[i].Split(','))[2];

            if (Username == checkUsername && Password == checkPassword)
            {
                result = "Successfully logged in";
                return result;
                break;

            }

         }

        result = "Wrong Login Combination";
        return result;
```